# What if I buy on spot and sell on futures?

Tags: derivatives

I am completely new to finance so I don't understand basic principles of derivatives market.
If I buy 100 shares of stock for 1.22 and then immediately enter the future contract to sell it for 1.25 in 6 months, will I certainly get a profit?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will be guaranteed a profit of 0.03 per share after 6 months.  In your example that would be about a 5% annual return.

*However*, futures on stocks are typically prices such that the return is a *risk-free* return, meaning you'd get the same rate of return (minus bid/ask spreads and any dividends expected to pay out) as investing in treasury bills over that same time period. In finance terms, it's the *future value* of the current spot price, using the risk-free interest rate as a discount rate.

So your profit should be no more than what you'd get from investing the same about in government bonds.  In fact it will probably be slightly less due to bid/ask spreads.

Futures on *commodities* are a slightly different story. The future price for commodities is not necessarily the future value of the spot price, since you can't just "buy" the spot commodity in a vacuum like you can with stocks - if you buy the commodity, you have to have somewhere to *store* it, which costs money (this is called "cost of carry" in commodity markets). That cost of carry is different for different commodities - meaning oil has a different storage cost than gold.

Comment: and if you buy a physical commodity ETF then presumably your ETF's value is going down by that same storage cost.

Comment: Note that futures can actually wind up having a negative value, if the commodity's price drops. Websearch will find descriptions of how this happens .